# z-index not working correctly

Tags: html, css, z-index

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why my z-index property is not working as it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/3v7Qq/

the banners at the sides (black) have a z-index of:

```
     z-index: -1;
```

and the banner which is yellow:

```
     z-index: 1000;
```

Here is a fiddle which is similar to what i'm working with, the two black squares have a lower z-index than the yellow banner, so why are they displaying on top?

The two grey triangles appear to be working correctly, I am trying to create a banner effect.

I have tried changing the values, but I can't seem to get it working and everywhere else I've looked says it should work, all elements have a 'position' attribute, so I can't see the problem.

Anyone?

Comment: You need to move those black banners outside of the yellow banner element. You can't arrange them to appear behind the yellow banner when they're child elements of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**z-index** works always in parallel elements not like your's code you have given the **z-index** in your child **div's** that's why its not working properly.

See the code how it works actually :-

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1"></div>  
<div class="div2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1 {
width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}

.div2 {
width:100px;
height:250px;
background:green;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
z-index:-10;
}
```

[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/4alXrpJt)

**And in your answser case after: before Pseudo-classes would be fine see the mentioned below demo how i have used before and after pseudo elements for your question i hope this will work for you and can give the z-index according to you requirement**

[demo answer of your question](http://tinkerbin.com/e27ZyTlD)

Comment: oh its k Jon the main thing is you got it the right solution what i need :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main">
    <span class="rightbanner"></span>
    <span class="leftbanner"></span>               
<nav>
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <span class="leftarrow"></span>
    <span class="rightarrow"></span>

    <ul id="nav_l">
        <li><a href="index.html" id="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.html" id="search">Search</a></li>  
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav_r">
        <li><a href="blog.html" id="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer_box_c" id="contact">Contact</a></li>     
    </ul>
</nav>
```

​    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

CSS:

```
.leftbanner {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px; 
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30%; 
    left: -20px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
}

.rightbanner {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px; 
    position: relative;  
    bottom: 30%; 
    right: -20px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px #808080;
}

.main{
  height:100px;
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v7Qq/5/)